# How to structure angular project with one level url?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, url-routing, angular-routing, angular-routerlink

Working on the website with several sections: post arranged by categories, video gallery, etc..
I need to have one level url (domain.com/page-address). I can get information of which view does this `page-address` has to load on the front side, However I could not organize angular project well.

I managed to make everything work but via components only, in single module and single router-outlet, by sending all routes to single component.
`routes: Routes = [{apth:  '**', , component: MainComponent }]`
and the component decides which component should be loaded.

```
/// viewType is retrieved from backend
<app-articles *ngIf="viewType == 'article_categories' || viewType == 'articles'" [viewType]='viewType'></app-articles>
<app-videos *ngIf="viewType == 'video_categories' || viewType == 'video_page'" [viewType]='viewType'></app-videos>
<app-page-not-found *ngIf="viewType == 'page-not-found'" ></app-page-not-found>
```

It seems really bad solution to me, as I can't use RouterLink and each click reloads whole website.

Also tried to make nested `RouterOutlets`, but could not make it work.

Do you have a solution for it?

Thank you

Comment: You should spend some more time reading Angular's Documentation for [Routing & Navigation](https://angular.io/guide/router#routing-and-navigation)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, I believe that one solution is to use Express Router on the the back-end to handle your routing. Explaining Express is out of the scope of a Stack Overflow answer but there is an abundance of tutorials on YouTube. I suggest the 'MEAN Stack Front-to-Back' series by Traversy Media. Its old, so parts of it require workarounds, but his workflow for setting up the router is the one I use with Angular to this day.

Your AppModule will contain:

```
routes: Routes = [
           {path:  '/pathA', , component: ComponentA },
           {path:  '/pathB', , component: ComponentB },
           {path:  '/pathC', , component: ComponentC, canActivate:[AuthGuard] },
]
```

but the actual routing will be handled via Express Router the back-end.

There are a lot of router packages for Node; Express is just the one that I use.